# Tweening svg elements from a random position to their actual position

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, tween

I've got a svg image file containing several polygons and paths. I want to display these polygons in my web page at random positions and create an animation to tween them to the position they have in the svg file. 
To summarize, I want to display and exploded svg and animate it to reconstruct itself.

I've searched for ways to do so but I can't find a way to get the position from the svg file as a destination and not a source.

Do you know how I could do so ?

EDIT : Here is what I currently have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="main">


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <svg version="1.1" width="1080" height="720" viewBox="0 0 1080 720">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st1{fill:#F8971D;}
      .st2{fill:#8DC63F;}
      .st3{fill:#00A18E;}
    </style>
    <g>
      <polygon class="st1" points="462.8,224.2 451.7,246.1 495.1,261.9  "/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <polygon class="st2" points="625.5,224.2 593.3,261.9 636.6,246.1  "/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path class="st3" d="M594.1,266.8l62.4,13.7l12.1-40.9L594.1,266.8z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to make st1, st2 and st3 appear at a random position in the page and create an animation that will make them go back to their original position (the one in the xml tag).

Thanks,

Comment: Show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I added a code sample